# zabbix is failed when updating database

Tags: zabbix

I have installed zabbix 3.2 and restored a database from old 2.4 version. After that zabbix started update the database , but failed.
How to solve this?
[Here is the log of zabbix-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRicG.png)
[here is 2nd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFhJw.png)

Answer (score 0):

you must try db transfer before assigning DB connection to Zabbix Server.
Same issue occurred to me when i relocated db.

1. keep into checklist to successfully transfer data .
2. Then to start Zabbix server pointing to DB.
3. You might also need to import DB template before data transfer ,if needed.